# onListItemClick within onDialogPositiveClick?

Tags: android

How can I refer to onListItemClick within onDialogPositiveClick? So the page does not open before/while the dialog box opens..Can I literally put onListItemClick in onDialogPositiveClick, or do I have to do something completely different? Here is my code...thanks for all/any help!

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements TheDialog.NoticeDialogListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] sites = {"Google", "Amazon", "Ebay" , "Reddit", "SmashingMag", "CCC"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylist_item, R.id.textView1, sites);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TheDialog();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Confirm");
    Intent i = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 1:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 2:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ebay.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 3:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.reddit.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 4:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.smashingmag.com"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    case 5:
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.myccc.corning-cc.edu"));
        startActivity(i); break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is not fire intent on list item click and move the switch code to

```
onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog){
Intent i = null;
switch(position){
case 0:
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(i); break;
case 1:
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com"));
    startActivity(i); break;
case 2:
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ebay.com"));
    startActivity(i); break;
case 3:
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.reddit.com"));
    startActivity(i); break;
case 4:
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.smashingmag.com"));
    startActivity(i); break;
case 5:
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.myccc.corning-cc.edu"));
    startActivity(i); break;
}}
```

This way user will only go to the next page when positive button is clicked, hope you want this kind of behavior.